# Create an php form and make an api request

Tags: php

I have to create an simple form:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>HTML page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="process.php">
    <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="rahul_sharma">
    <button type="submit">send</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

From my process.php file, I have to hit an url like below:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/api?rahul_sharma
```

which will give back an json response

```
{"status":"Success","username":"your username is RAHULSHARMA"}
```

If status is success, have to display the username value.

New to php.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Under-researched.  No php coding attempt. Too Broad.

Answer (score 0):

you can call API using [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

```
    $url='https://stackoverflow.com/api?';

    $call_url = $url . $_POST['first_name'] ;

    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => $call_url,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    echo $response;//{"status":"Success","username":"your username is RAHULSHARMA"}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `process.php` file, you can use the `$_POST` superglobal to fetch the form data.

```
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
```

After that you can concatenate it using the `.` operator to form the url.

```
$url = "https://your-api-site.com/api?" . $firstname;
```

Next you can fetch the content from the url using a curl request.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

The result from fetching the url will be obtained in the `$output` variable. Suppose the result from your API is a JSON string like the one you provided, you can use `json_decode` PHP function to convert it to an associative array.

```
$result = json_decode($output);
```

Now you can use `if` conditions to check if `status` is `Success` and display the username.

```
if ($result['status'] == "Success") {
  echo $result['username'];
}
```